# What's causing this position change? Jquery animation

Tags: jquery

This script works well:

```
var $count = 4;
var $row = 10;

function across() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow .active .current');
    var $next = $active.next();

    $next.addClass('current');
    $active.animate({ left: '+=100px' }, 800, 'swing').removeClass('current');
    $row += 10;
    $count--;

    if ($count == 0) { 
        $count = 4;
        $row = 10;
        down();
        $($active).stop();
        $('#slideshow .active .bed').animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1);
        $('.div .bed:first-child').addClass('current');

    }
}
function down() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow .active');
    var $next = $active.next();

    $next.fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
    $active.fadeOut("slow").removeClass('active');

    if (!$next.length) {
        $("#slideshow .div:first-child").fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
    }
}
$(function() {
  setInterval(across, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QSfgG/30/

But there is a problem.

On the green parent square, the orange, purple and grey divs slide right across, yet on the other squares, the divs only barely slide onto the left.

It's something to do with the down() function on line 16 of the script. When that's taken out, all of the divs slide on the same amount. However, I can't leave out the down(), as I need it to be called before

```
$('#slideshow .active .bed').animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1);
$('.div .bed:first-child').addClass('current');
```

on lines 18 and 19. This is so the user doesn't see the divs snapping back to their original position. To clarify, I need the orange, purple and grey divs to slide on the same amount, **and I need the parent div to fade out before the user sees the divs snapping back to their original position.**

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Comment: Hi Dom, thanks for your detailed answer! I did manage to find a solution on my own, but from what I can see yours is more elegant, so I'll give it a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with this line:

`$('#slideshow .active .bed').animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1);`

Basically, you are changing the `left` of all `.bed` to -120px (moving it off screen entirely).

I recommend adding an unique class, animate it, then remove it after the count.  Here is an example:

```
var $count = 4;
var $row = 10;

function across() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow .active .current');
    var $next = $active.next();
    $active.addClass('move'); //add class

    $next.addClass('current');
    $active.animate({ left: '+=100px' }, 800, 'swing').removeClass('current');
    $row += 10;
    $count--;

    if ($count == 0) { 
        $count = 4;
        $row = 10;
        down();
        $($active).stop();
        $('.move').animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1); //animate class
        $('.div .bed:first-child').addClass('current');
        $('.move').removeClass('move'); //remove class
    }
}
function down() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow .active');
    var $next = $active.next();

    $next.fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
    $active.fadeOut("slow").removeClass('active');

    if (!$next.length) {
        $("#slideshow .div:first-child").fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
    }
}
$(function() {
  setInterval(across, 1000);
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/QSfgG/42/

However, you can also go about it by using an array.

```
var $count = 4;
var $row = 10;
var $divs =[]; //make array to hold "beds"

function across() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow .active .current');
    var $next = $active.next();
    $divs.push($active); //push active "bed"

    $next.addClass('current');
    $active.animate({ left: '+=100px' }, 800, 'swing').removeClass('current');
    $row += 10;
    $count--;

    if ($count == 0) { 
        $count = 4;
        $row = 10;
        down();
        $($active).stop();
        for(var a = 0; a < $divs.length; a++){
         $($divs[a]).animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1) //move each "bed" in array 100px
        }
        $divs=[]; //reset array
        $('.div .bed:first-child').addClass('current');

    }
}
function down() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow .active');
    var $next = $active.next();

    $next.fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
    $active.fadeOut("slow").removeClass('active');

    if (!$next.length) {
        $("#slideshow .div:first-child").fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
    }
}
$(function() {
  setInterval(across, 1000);
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/QSfgG/40/